# Run batch file on remote computer using PSExec and continue execution, don't wait for remote process to end

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-control, psexec, wait

I would like to run a program (a batch file with an infinite loop inside) on a remote host using PSEXec, and continue execution afterwards. My problem is that when I run a command like:

```
psexec -d -u user -p password \\192.168.42.42 "D:\myscript.bat", the calling command-windows stays open, but does not return, because d:\mysscript.bat contains a loop that makes the process run infinitely (intentionally).
```

What I would like to achieve is a behaviour that I can start a process remotely, which keeps running on a remote system, but execution in the calling command-window continues (i.e. psexec returns even though the remote process is still running).

How can I achieve the desired behaviour with psexec? At the moment, the process on the caller side waits for the remote process to end, but does not return.

Comment: Have you tried executing the batch file using cmd.exe and the `start` command to execute the batch?  I don't know that it will work but it is the first thing that I would try.  Also, is the user `user` logged in?.. what do you expect to happen if they aren't?  Should the logged in session remain?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially just use nested batch files and use psexec to call a local batch on the remote machine? https://jpsoft.com/help/call.htm